Can a window fan keep heat indoors?
Can a window fan keep heat indoors when it is colder outside than inside? Suppose a window with 1 unit of area must be open. If the goal is to decrease the rate at which the inside / outside temperatures will reach equilibrium, is it better to have a fan blow outside, have a fan blow inside, or have no fan at all with the window open? Which setup will result in the highest indoor temperature after 1 hour?

Please perform the experiment you suggest and let us know the results.

Whichever way the fan is pointed, cold air will be drawn into the house, so no fan is better.  If the fan is pointed in, cold air is blown directly into the house and warm air exits through vents and cracks in the house; if the fan is pointed out, warm air is blown directly out through the window and cold air is drawn in through the vents and cracks. If there is no fan, warm air leaves the window only through convective flow, which is slower. An even better solution, however, is to stick the fan in the window but leave it turned off, since that will block some of the convective flow.
